# Why can't I send Mutex<*mut c_void> between threads?

Tags: rust

I need to share an object created from C++ between Rust threads. I have wrapped it in a `Mutex` construct, so now it is safe to be sent between threads. However the compiler won't let me do what.

```
error[E0277]: `*mut std::ffi::c_void` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> sendsync.rs:14:2
    |
14  |     thread::spawn(move || {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*mut std::ffi::c_void` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Api`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut std::ffi::c_void`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `OpaqWrapper`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Api`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Mutex<Api>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Api>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@sendsync.rs:14:16: 19:3 safe_obj:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Api>>]`
```

How should I implement this according to Rust rules? Here is the code:

```
use std::{
    sync::{
        Arc,Mutex,
    },
    ptr,
    thread::{self},
};
pub struct OpaqWrapper {
    pub obj_ptr: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
}
pub struct Api(OpaqWrapper);

fn spawn_api_thread(safe_obj: Arc<Mutex<Api>>) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        {
            let my_api = safe_obj.lock().unwrap();
            // my_api.whatever();
        }
    });
}

fn main() {
    let api = Api(
        OpaqWrapper {
            obj_ptr: ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    );
    let shared_api= Arc::new(Mutex::new(api));
    for _ in 0..10 {
        spawn_api_thread(shared_api.clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that the pointer inside `OpaqWrapper` is owned, then you can manually implement `Send` on `OpaqWrapper`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Short version

Passing something to a thread requires that it be `Send`.

```
T:Send => Mutex<T>:Send+Sync =>  Arc<Mutex<T>>:Send
```

so it is enough to mark `Api` as `Send`

### Long version

Passing something to a thread requires that it be `Send`.

`Arc<T>` only automatically gets `Send` (and `Sync`) if `T` is `Send` and `Sync`. The source contains something like this:

```
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Send for Arc<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Sync for Arc<T> {}
```

However, `Mutex` only requires `Send` for it to be both `Sync` and `Send`, its code contains:

```
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for Mutex<T> { }
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Sync for Mutex<T> { }
```

This means for `Arc<Mutex<Api>>` to be `Sync`, you need `Mutex<Api>` to be
 `Sync+Send` which will happen if `Api` is `Send`. To get this you need to mark either `Api` or `OpaqWrapper` as `Send`.

```
unsafe impl Send for Api {}
```

Note you dont need to mark them as `Sync` as the `Mutex` gets that automatically.

Comment: *The same is true for `Mutex`*: actually, `Mutex<T>` is both `Send` and `Sync` when `T` is only `Send`. This is why `Api` does not need to be `Sync`.

Comment: And none of this needs `Mutex` **or** `Arc` (and those are both *probably* wrong for this case anyway). You can just do `struct Foo(*mut Bar)` and impl `Send` for that.

Comment: I was assuming the API was a singleton that was not safe to be used concurrently on separate threads, and that was the reason for using a Mutex+Arc.

Comment: Thanks @trentcl I've tried to incorporate that into the description.